# Can you test the bounds of a parameter in phpunit?

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd

Say I have the following method:

```
public function setDeliveryDay(int $deliveryDay)
{
    $this->deliveryDay = $deliveryDay;
}
```

I want to write a test to make sure this setter only allowed ISO-8601 values (so `1` to `7`), how would I achieve this?

It seems that the only real way would be to test every possible integer below or above 1 and 7 respectively?

Of course this wouldn't be sensible, especially if you're expecting it to throw an exception.

At first I tested the lower bound:

```
$this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
$obj->setDeliveryDay(0);
```

and in another test the upper bound (because `expectException` only supports one exception per test):

```
$this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
$obj->setDeliveryDay(8);
```

Of course this wouldn't stop someone setting it to -1 or -842 or 9 or 3835 and so on.

Is there a type of assertion I'm missing here or an accepted best practice to test bounds?

Comment: @GhostCat I'm still fiddling around, trying some things, so I can decide which provides most insight and possibly mark as the correct answer. Generally though I think the real answer is "you can't - unless you adopt some other technique." My upvotes also indicated their initial helpfulness.

Comment: Anyway, nicely written question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is create a simple ValueObject for weekday, that does not expose the numbers and uses static factory-methods to set the value. That way you can be reasonably safe that the correct value is passed by type hinting for that object.

When it comes to testing your code with `int` being passed I would not worry about catching all impossible values. You only test for expected misuse, so I would only test for `0` but you could also do a test for `8` if you want to signify the upper bound. If it's not easily discernable which numbers might be valid and which not you should still limit the test cases to the most plausible ones and then only test further cases, e.g. for 3835 when you encounter a bug because of that number, just to be safe it will not reappear.

If you want to catch these cases you might want to look into mutation testing. Alternatively you could pass in random test values, e.g. with `rand(8, PHP_INT_MAX)`, but I would not recommend this as it leads to flaky tests and makes it harder to track what values were used and why.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of a ValueObject would that not be bypassable if someone just passed in an int anyway? Or am I not getting you correctly.

Comment: Depends how you build it. You could do something like this: https://3v4l.org/p3Vbf **edit:** so a constructor for each weekday. Alternatively you could throw an Exception in the constructor when $iso8601Weekday < 1 or > 7. Then you end up with your problem but you limited the scope to the value object instead of each place in your code where you expect a weekday

Comment: I suppose nothing's stopping anyone from just ignoring the value object and passing in an int anyway.

Comment: Yes, a type hint does. You will get a TypeError when you pass in an int or anything else other than a Weekday-object. See this update code snippet: https://3v4l.org/41mWo

Comment: Riiight I get you. I quite like this. Whether or not I'll implement it I'm unsure as it *may* be overkill in my case, but solid idea. Cheers

Comment: I agree, nice answer; worth the accept; and another upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are turning to a turning into "quickcheck" like testing, there isn't so much you can do. QuickCheck is a testing approach originally coming out of the haskell world, but it seems there is a php [library](https://github.com/steos/php-quickcheck) as well. They are all about "property based testing":

> Generative testing, also called property-based testing, is about describing the behaviour of your system in terms of properties that should hold true for all possible input.

In other words: the idea of such frameworks is to make sure valid input passes; and *any* bad input fails.

If you don't want to go down that path ... I would do this:

- write one testcase that tests the few valid values within a loop
- write two other testcases for the **boundaries**
- write another testcase that loops and tries a bunch of invalid values (for example based on random numbers)

Final word: when you go for "random" values, make sure to use a **seed** somewhere and to log that - to ensure you can reproduce a failing test later on.